# Inactivity Kill-switch for SystemVerilog Testbench Simulation (VCS)

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Hi and thanks for seeing this.

I was pondering over the idea of an inactivity killswitch for SystemVerilog simulation.

Is there a way in which a prolonged (programmable) duration of inactivity when running "simv" can trigger an internal event to call '$finish' ? Or is it possible using the VCS command ?

Lets brainstorm. And let me know if something is unclear.

RRS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VHDL I use a resolved signal.

Each process that generates or analyses data writes `0` to that signal while it is working.  Once it is in a state for the simulation to finish, it writes `1`.

Only when all processes are happy does the signal change state to a `1` (it's either `X` or `0` the rest of the time).

The clock generation processes monitor this signal and when it becomes `1` they stop producing clock pulses; no further transitions are scheduled, and the simulator knows to stop.

Presumably Verilog can do something similar.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea. At this point I use a killswitch which counts down to 0 and triggers $finish. I was thinking if there was a way to access the event list in the simulator and then trigger when there are no more events remaining to simulate. I guess the big problem here is that the clock transition is considered as an event. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The simulator does precisely that (it looks at the events list and terminates when there are none scheduled) and I make sure that I turn off all the sources of events (which in my testbenches, is just the clocks, even though the testbenches are very behavioural).

Answer (score 1):

Inside the chip design companies that I've worked for, this is called a "quiescent check", but I'm not sure if that's an industry standard name.  You implement "instrumentation code" that checks that the system has acheived quiescence.  V̶e̶r̶i̶s̶i̶t̶y̶'̶s̶  Cadence's [Specman-e tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specman) does this quite elegantly with its objection to end of test mechanism (`raise_objection(MAIN_TEST_DONE)/drop_objection(MAIN_TEST_DONE)`).  Essentially, monitors throughout throughout the system "raise" an objection at the beginning of simulation ( i.e. increment the counter), then when the simulation runs, they determine that their piece of the DUT is quiescent and they "lower" the objection (i.e. decrement this global counter).  When there are no more objections to ending the test, (i.e. the global counter is 0), then `$finish` is called.  The monitors can raise and lower objections throughout the test, but if and when the counter ever reaches 0, the test is `$finish`'d.

Universal Verification Methodology (UVM) took up this methodology from Specman and it is described here in their [UVM Reference Manual](http://www.accellera.org/downloads/standards/uvm/UVM_1.1_Class_Reference_Final_06062011.pdf#page=183).  UVM is implemented with Verilog first and foremost, so you could definitely use their freely available library to implement "quiescent checking".  Cadence's Specman UVM reference manual also describes this mechanism at http://support.cadence.com .  Unfortunately, Cadence requires that you be a customer before they'll show you their documents and thus you must use a non-Google search engine to find what you want.  It's a bit of a pain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... this makes a lot of sense. I am using Synopsys VCS, so my guess is that I must find the equivalent for "quiescent check" in VCS. Is there a way to access the event list/counter without going through UVM ?

Comment: AFAIK, the quiescent check doesn't come from VCS by default ( as it does in the Specman environment.)  You can either implement this global counter yourself or import it from uvm.  BTW, it is essential to keep track of _who_ has an outstanding objection to end of test for debug purposes.  I'd implement it in C++ as a `set` and then hook up VCS with DPI calls to `incr(my_rtl_path)` `decr(my_rtl_path)`.